# Seting up Azure Search for development environments

Tags: c#, full-text-search, azure-cognitive-search

I want to set up Azure Search however I am not sure how to do it in the develop environment without spending a too much money.

Let's say there are 20 developers in the office and the solution needs 3 indexes. To have it available in the dev environment, we need to spend around $1000 every month which is quite expensive, while there is almost no calls to it.

What is the solution to avoid that?

Here is  [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/search/) to their pricing
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know what the cheapest development way is? Or how to bring the cost down because you have too much data that you sometimes need to search on?

Comment: I don't have much data. It just needs to work for developers as well and since each developer has his own data, they should have a separated inedx set

Comment: Sorry, I think there is no way to get around the costs of microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the right Visual Studio license (Enterprise, I believe), you get 150$ monthly credit towards Azure costs. That could be a way around the pricing scheme as well (for dev purposes).

Relevant link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/credit-for-visual-studio-subscribers/